# Arreglo ascendente y descendente en js

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones

Estoy estudiando Javascript y estoy realizando un ejercicio propuesto de un libro, la sentencia if me sale bien, el problema es que no entra al else aún cuando la condición debería apuntar hacia el.

```js
rangoPaso(10, 2, 2);

function rangoPaso(start, end, paso){
    let contar = [];
    
    if (start < end){
        
        for(let i = start; i <= end; i += paso){
            contar.push(i);
        }
    }else{
        for(let j = end; j >= start; j -= paso){
            contar.push(j);
        }
    }
    console.log(contar);
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la condición que debería entrar en el else? No estaría mal que explicaras el funcionamiento del algoritmo y también sería bueno mostrar otros ejemplos de las entradas y lo que el programa debería de tener como salida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu código si entra al else, como puedes comprobar en el snippet siguiente:

```js
rangoPaso(10, 2, 2);

function rangoPaso(start, end, paso){
    let contar = [];
    
    if (start < end){
        
        for(let i = start; i <= end; i += paso){
            contar.push(i);
        }
    }else{
        console.log("si entro");
        for(let j = end; j >= start; j -= paso){
            contar.push(j);
        }
    }
    console.log(contar);
}
```

El error está en la lógica del segundo for. Dado que en cada iteración vas a ir restando el *paso*, siempre debes ir del inicio (10) al fin (2), no del fin al inicio. La condición para mantenerse dentro del ciclo ya la tenías con el operador correcto:

```js
rangoPaso(10, 2, 2);

function rangoPaso(start, end, paso){
    let contar = [];
    
    if (start < end){
        
        for(let i = start; i <= end; i += paso){
            contar.push(i);
        }
    }else{
        for(let j = start; j >= end; j -= paso){
            contar.push(j);
        }
    }
    console.log(contar);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración, me sirvió de mucho.